# Office 2007 Mail Merge: How do I view field names instead of data?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, mail-merge

I've just received a document which forms the basis of a mail merge as an attachment and I need to view the field names like they display in 2003 with the double chevrons e.g.

> <<titles>><<initials>><<surname>>

However even though I get a dialogue as I open the docx file saying that it is going to attempt to merge from a file (which I don't have) and I cancel that operation the document still displays merge data e.g.

> Mr A Test

Instead of the field names. I have clicked on the fields which turn grey to demonstrate that they are fields but I can't find a way to make it display the field names not the data. I don't even know where it's getting the data from as I don't have the data source file for the document to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its in the options for word. Something like "view field names instead of data" and a check box.

Answer (score 6):

For Word 2010... Choose File/options/Advanced/Show Field Codes instead of their values (about half way down the advanced options in the Show Document ontent section)

Comment: Also works in Word 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work as I have a different version of Office, but try:

> Ctrl+F9 to insert each pair of field delimiters { } and Alt+F9 to turn them off.

So, try inserting a blank pair, and see if this turns delimiters on.

Comment: @One Monkey This is actually the easier way once you learn the shortcut keys